# Looking for a popular, well known example of closed-source software which uses LGPL code, and says so

Tags: licensing, lgpl, closed-source

For advocacy purposes, I'm looking for a good example of some popular/widely-known closed-source and generally paid-for software application/package which uses dynamically linked **LGPL**-licensed libraries, and isn't shy of saying so in its installer dialogs or preferably in its "About" info and/or online documentation once the application is installed.

Basically I'm looking for evidence which will back up an argument "*If ...big vendor... doesn't have a problem shipping ...hugely popular SW... with an LGPL dependency, neither should you.*"

(Links to any screenshots or online copies of documentation which demonstrate the usage without me needing to actually acquire the software would be most appreciated).

Comment: "Commercial" and "closed-source" are not the same thing. Ubuntu is commercial, but most of it is open-source; MySQL is highly commercial, but open-source. And vv., there is enough non-commercial software with a non-free license or even binary-only distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With very few exceptions, you can take your pick of proprietary and closed source applications for Linux or Android.  Glibc is LGPL and is linked with practically everything.  Autodesk, MathWorks, Oracle, IBM, Adobe, Google, Samsung, Amazon, Nvidia, Motorola, and many more companies incorporate and depend on LGPL and even some GPL components in their software and hardware products.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, googling 'autodesk "Gnu lesser general public license"' gets me perfect fodder, and they seem to have consolidated their download obligations nicely at http://www.autodesk.com/lgplsource

Comment: Very interesting topic for shareware writer :)